# Scope to fetch Associated data from Database Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations

Basically i wanted to use scope to fetch data using association.

Association between user and posts.

```
 belongs_to :user # on posts model
 has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy #on user model
```

Query

Database has number records of posts created by various users, So i wanted to fetch all those posts whose post.user.name doesn't have a pattern (integer etc) in it.

I wish to use

```
Post.scope_name
```

Comment: Can u give one example for "post.user.name doesn't have a pattern (integer etc) in it"

Comment: Amit, Somehow I have figured out the desired results using the scope which i have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this

```
scope :posts_by, joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.id = posts.user_id").where('users.name REGEXP ? ', "my_pattern")
```